# How to handle propely the duplicate name error on registration form ? (Drupal 8)

Tags: drupal

In Drupal 8, when I try to register a user with a name that is already taken, I get a blank page with this message : "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." It's because of the integrity constraint violation in mysql :

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Alain-fr' for key 'user__name': INSERT INTO {users_field_data} (uid, langcode, preferred_langcode, preferred_admin_langcode, name, pass, mail, timezone, status, created, changed, access, login, init, default_langcode) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9, :db_insert_placeholder_10, :db_insert_placeholder_11, :db_insert_placeholder_12, :db_insert_placeholder_13, :db_insert_placeholder_14)
```

How can I handle this and propely rendering a watchdog message like "This username it's already taken" instead of this ugly error ?

Comment: I think your project is not configured properly. Try to install new drupal 8 instance. And try there, as drupal never throw Fatal Error on registration. Drupal already handle this exceptions.

Comment: Follow this https://www.drupal.org/node/2795809. Problem is with `userprotect_entity_field_access` function.

Comment: I finally find that is the profile module that cause this problem ! When a profile field is added to the registration form the issue occur